# C++ on Unix: Redirecting Shell Output

Tags: c++, shell, system

I have a command that compiles *test.cpp* and is supposed to store output in the output file. Here is an example of my generated cmd:

> g++ tmp/test.cpp -o tmp/test &> tmp/compile.out

when I use *system()*, it does not work. Even though it creates output file, it still prints everything to the main console window. When I execute it in terminal, it works just fine.

I also tried use *popen()* and *fgets()* (just copying the code from [here](http://www.minoraddition.com/2011/03/23/popen-execute-shell-command-from-cc/http://www.minoraddition.com/2011/03/23/popen-execute-shell-command-from-cc/)) but same happened. I probably could just fork my process and use *freopen* or something but I have sockets and multiple threads running in the background. I guess they would be duplicated as well, which is not good.

Any ideas why it may fail?

Comment: Which platform are you on? According to the `system` manpage on my local Linux install, it specifically uses `/bin/sh` to execute the string. Redirect syntax differs between shells, and `&>` may be a bash extension. Whether `/bin/sh` is a symlink to bash may depend on platform/distribution.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the man-page of `system`, it invokes `sh` which is the standard bourne shell (not bash, Bourne Again SHell). And the bourne shell doesn't understand `&>`. So you might need to use the old style:

```
g++ tmp/test.cpp -o tmp/test >tmp/compile.out 2>&1
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank You. Will mark as an answer in 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following variant on `popen()` and it worked for me under Mac OS X 10.7.2, gcc 4.2.1:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fpipe;
    char *cmd = "foo &> bar";

    if ( !(fpipe = (FILE*)popen(cmd,"r")) ) {
        perror("Problems with pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiling:

```
gcc -Wall test.c -o test
```

The binary `test` creates a file called `bar`, which contains the following output:

```
sh: foo: command not found
```

Which is what I would see if I typed `foo &> bar` at the shell.